# ESP8266 module don't responce

Tags: android-studio, wifi

I write follow code for connect to `ESP8266`  Module in android studio
in yesterday.

```
    class BackgroundTask 



        String ip,message,mm;




        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ip=params[0];
            message=params[1];
            try {
                s=new Socket(ip,8888);
                dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeUTF(message);
               din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

                 mm=din.readUTF();
                Log.e("socket",mm.toString());


                Log.e("socket","after null");
                dos.close();

                if (s.isConnected()) {
                    Log.e("socket","1" );

                    Log.e("socket",m.m);

                }else {
                    Log.e("socket","2");

                }
                din.close();
                s.close();

            }catch (IOException e){}
            return null;
        }


    }
```

that's right and connect to connect to module
note that i use a real device and `wifi controller esp8266` app for test.
but module don't response to my app 
everybody know about this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure you are passing the ip address parameter correctly? And you need to identify the error messages you are getting (I imagine there is something you can call to get them). This sort of application needs even more careful exception handling than usual.

Comment: Yes ip that's right

Comment: Have you identified the error message?

Comment: i haven't  error but can't get response from module ... i can send signal to module and on led but ...

Comment: @MandyShaw  have u  idea?

Comment: If you are certain that you are picking up the parameters correctly, and that all the calls you are making are successful (I am still questioning this, given that you don't seem to be doing much checking for exceptions), then you'll have to wait for an Android socket programming expert to pop up, sorry.

Comment: P.S. there's an example here with what looks like some proper exception handling in: http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/